# How to install python external module in shell of replit?

Tags: shell, installation, module, replit

**I'm using pip install pandas in shell of replit and I'm getting os error in shell**

I tried pip install pandas in shell of replit,and I expected installation of pandas in the shell but I got command not installed.multiple versions of this command were found in Nix and could not install packages due to an os error